# Обновление SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

```
private void saveChangeRus() {
   String word = txtWord.getText().toString().trim();
   String translation = txtMultiLine.getText().toString().trim();
   int type = 1;

   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD, word);
   values.put(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_TRANSLATION, translation);
   values.put(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_TYPE, type);

   // Вставляем новый ряд в базу данных и запоминаем его идентификатор
   long newRowId = db.update(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD + "= ?", new String[]{word});

   // Выводим сообщение в успешном случае или при ошибке
   if (newRowId == -1) { // Если ID  -1, значит произошла ошибка
      Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка при сохранении изменений", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Слово " + "\"" + word + "\"" + " отредактировано", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

В таблице 4 колонки `word (text)`, `translation (text)`, `type (integer)` и `_id (integer)`.

До добавления в таблицу колонки `type (integer`) все работало, а теперь при попытке обновить программа вылетает. В чем может быть дело?

Вот что выдается в консоли

```html
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: test.proj1, PID: 2379
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference
                      at .ActivityEdit.onClickEditButton(ActivityEdit.java:170)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Ошибку какую выдаёт?

Comment: Стек трейс выложите

Comment: Ну скорей всего вы не обновили бд, т.е в вашем приложении по-прежнему используется старая версия бд, в которой этой колонки ещё нет. Удалите и заново установите приложение. Но что бы все корректно работало у пользователей надо повышать версию бд и писать скрипт для обновления бд если недостаточно будет удалить и заново создать бд.

Comment: БД обновлена, другие методы по поиску записей с новой колонкой работают

Comment: Ну по этому стектрейсу чекбокс у вас равен null. Там прям так и написано

Comment: Да, я кажется понял. Без чекбокса обновление БД работает нормально. Буду разбираться. Спасибо.